# Extracting data from an unknown encoding file

Tags: arrays, file, encoding, dos, encode

We use testing equipment (1995 year manufacturing) powered by MS DOS. Analog-digital converter records information in the file.
In [picture[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5W9bI.jpg)] is shown the structure of that file.
In [picture[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXInF.jpg)] is shown the oscillogram that constructed according to the data from the file (program for opening the file on MS DOS).
Below I placed link to this file (google drive).

This file contains the data that need for me - the massive of point of oscillogram. I want have opportunities to keep, analyze and print this chart on Windows or Linux (not MS DOS). So I need to extract data from the file.

But I can't make it. And no program (known to me) can't open this file. I analyzed a few first byte and they point to program 'TRAS v4.99'. This program is on MS DOS.

But I really hope, that it is really to get data without this program.

P.S. If anyone will say it is impossible - it is will well too because I haven't found point of view yet:)

Thank you for your time! Best regards!

[LINK TO FILE ON GOOGLE DISK - 00014380.K00](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pb1eoarsv7Sx2hGkWlMG4kfFBbj_1Zev)

STRUCTURE OF FILE
[image: Structure of file]

OPENING FILE VIA PROGRAM IN MS DOS
[image: Oscillogram is constructed from data from the file]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea on how you can tackle this problem. Since the format is relatively well specified in the handbook you can use the Java programming language for example with something like `java.io.RandomAccessFile` to read arrays of bytes. These arrays of bytes can then be converted to Java primitive types OR to string according to the data type. After this conversion you can the print out the data in a human readable format.

Below you can find some sample code to give you an idea of what you could do with this approach (I have not tested the code, it is not complete, it is just to give you an idea of what you can do):

```
public static void readBinaryfile() throws IOException {
    java.io.RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile("test.bin", "r");
    byte[] addKenStrBytes = new byte[12];
    randomAccessFile.read(addKenStrBytes);
    String addKenStr = new String(addKenStrBytes, "UTF-8");
    // TODO: Do something with addKenStr.
    System.out.println(addKenStr);

    byte[] kopfSizeBytes = new byte[2];
    randomAccessFile.read(kopfSizeBytes);
    // TODO: Do something with kopfSizeBytes
    System.out.println(convertToInt(kopfSizeBytes));

    byte[] addRufNrCounterBytes = new byte[6];
    randomAccessFile.read(addRufNrCounterBytes);
    long addRufNrCounter = convertToLong(addRufNrCounterBytes);
    // TODO: Do something with addRufNrCounter
    System.out.println(addRufNrCounter);

    byte[] endAdrBytes = new byte[4];
    randomAccessFile.read(endAdrBytes);
    // TODO: Do something with endAdrBytes
    System.out.println(convertToLong(endAdrBytes));

    // Continue here and after you reached the end of the record repeat until you reached the end off the file
}

private static int convertToInt(byte[] bytes) {
    if(bytes.length > 4) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    int buffer = 0;
    for(byte b : bytes) {
        buffer |= b;
        buffer = buffer << 8;
    }
    return buffer;
}

private static long convertToLong(byte[] bytes) {
    if(bytes.length > 8) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    long buffer = 0L;
    for(byte b : bytes) {
        buffer |= b;
        buffer = buffer << 8;
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

Note that fields with more than 8 bytes need to be most probably converted to strings. This is not complete code, just an example to give you an idea on how you can tackle this problem.

Comment: oh, thank you a lot. It seems, I begin to understand this. After I will write about result.